# efficient bean tree like structure parsing

Tags: java, algorithm, sax, stax

```
Message
  date: Date
  remarks: String
  person: ContactPerson

Person
  name: PersonName
  surname: PersonName

ContactPerson extends Person

PersonName
  value: 
  language: String
```

Is it possible to use StAX or SAX - or whichever other frameworks might help to recursively parse a bean tree structure like this and replace some characters from remarks, name.value and surname.value?

I originally wrote a recursive algorithm to do this but it takes about 4 seconds for a large bean tree. Are there any frameworks/different solutions to optimize this?

UPDATE1:
The types are usually extended from a base type which contains the interesting properties that should be replaced. For example, ContactPerson extends Person which contains the name and surname from which the value should be replaced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to explicitly set properties in nested beans by some kind of property path,  like "message.person.name.value" you could try using something like `BeanUtils.setProperty` which allows for accessing nested properties by path expression.

Comment: yes, however I need to introspect based on the super classes - please check UPDATE1

Comment: doesn't matter if the instances extend a base type or not - the subclass inherits all the same properties from the base class.